# Irksome review pop-up window size/design

Tags: feature-request

When working with the review queue, the windows that actually contain the Close Button are sized and designed so that you have to scroll down to get to the Close Button. There is usually plenty of white space, so there is no reason for this. Can we get the Close Button to appear on the screen unless there is such a roster of options that it gets pushed off the screen?

[image]

Comment: Can you do a screen shot?

Comment: Done. I can move the window, of course, but it always reappears in the same annoying place.